# IE Timing out after 5 minutes

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

We have an ASP.NET web application which calls a web service in SAP. This web service returns
a dataset which is then written out as an xlsx file. If the processing takes less than 5 minutes,
it runs fine. However, if it takes more than 5 minutes, the IE page shows "This page can't be 
displayed". This behavior is consistent for IE9,IE10,IE11. It runs fine in Chrome.

Any ideas to solve this? 
I tried checking "Enable Enhanced Protected mode" and that did not work. 
my Web.config has httpRuntime executionTimeout="1800"
(30 minutes)

The only thing I've found online is that it should call the web service Asynchronously 
and have it return status to the web browser so it won't time out. Since it works in Chrome, I'm hoping there is a simpler solution.

Comment: How is it calling the web service, through server side or js?

Comment: server side C# class library

Comment: then it may not be an issue with the browser per se. Any stacktrace you and capture and post out here? Also show the code causing exception. See if you can replicate this by mocking.